# Is there a way to detect if someone has charles proxy or a network tracking app, tracking your program's requests/apis

Tags: python-requests, charles-proxy

Is there a way to detect if someone has charles proxy or a network tracking app, tracking your program's requests/apis. And if so is there a way to prevent such a thing.

Just wanted a bit of insight into this, any information is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to achieve it: Here are two solutions I could think of

- After the SSL finish, you can get the certificate and check whether or not it's a self-signed certificate. Then, you might reject the Request connection.
- Use the SSL-Pinning technique that only accepts the certificate from your own and rejects others. It will prevent the app is intercepted from Charles Proxy or other Proxy tools like Proxyman, Fiddler, and Wireshark.